# Azure Logic Apps: Insert MULTIPLE rows to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I was wondering if there is a way to insert multiple rows to Azure SQL Database using the SQL connector in Logic App.

I've got a HTTP GET request which returns an array of results. I want to use the items of this array as data source for row inserts.

I know there is a way to iterate through arrays in Logic Apps using "foreach". I have tried this and the "Insert Row" action fails because "foreach is not supported in API connector action".

Is there a different way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't yet have a batch insert but it is on the backlog. However it's still possible by writing a stored procedure that takes an array. For example you could write a stored proc that takes an OPENJSON array and inserts one row per item

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will wait for batch insert action to be released and meanwhile give that stored procedure approach a go.

Comment: Is there any update on BATCH Insert for SQL Server in Logic Apps ?

Comment: Any update on backlog?

Comment: I've worked with Azure Logic Apps daily for over a year now. Guys, seriously, don't use Azure Logic Apps for anything of importance. It's very obviously a second class citizen, getting very little attention from Microsoft. It's also unreliable, buggy, extremely slow, extremely expensive, and essentially undeployable and untestable using standard CI/CD pipelines and unit testing tooling.